# "Times of their choosing" or "times of their choice"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Should we use *choosing* or *choice* in the sentence below?

> You may find that engaging the required range of participants requires
>   traveling to participants' home or workplace, at times of their
>   **choosing/choice**.

Comment: Both are fine, but in practice [at a time of your choosing](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22at+a+time+of+your+choosing%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) is more common than [at a time of your choice](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22at+a+time+of+your+choice%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). Any supposed difference in grammaticality or meaning is spurious, imho.

Comment: It's simply a matter of parallel construction.  It would be also perfectly fine to say *You may find that to engage the required range of participants will require your to travel to the participants' home or workplace at a time of their choice.*

Answer (score 6):

Both are correct, with *choosing* functioning as a gerund.